# how to put a form value in to variable in php?

Tags: php, forms, submit

i am doing url masking to pass the values. the code below input a variable.

```
 <form >
        <input type="text" name="name"  required />
        <button type="button" id="btn" action="drive/<?php echo$_GET['name'];?>
    /">submit</button>
    </form>
```

i want to pass the value like

```
 drive/12
```

but when i click the submit button it is passing like

```
 drive/?name=3.
```

what is the correct way of submitting the value?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to just set the form method to POST.

Otherwise, you'll have to add a javascript handler to the form's submit event, encode the text field and redirect the browser to the desired url.

Answer (score 0):

the form URL is where your action should be and the submit stays the same - right now the NAME is being passed as a get by default for the form.

```
 <form method="post" action="drive/<?php echo$_GET['name'];?">
        <input type="text" name="name"  required />
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: it cant work. now it is passing like /drive/<?php echo$_GET['name'];?>

Comment: your file needs to be in php - if you are seeing LITERATELY PHP tags then u are not writting in PHP file but in HTML.